# The main character is reincarnated in his own world, due to his crest holding him back from being able to reach his full potential

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, reincarnation

In this manga, the MC was born in another world. He never reincarnated, but later on he does, due to his crest. He had a lot of knowledge for magic, but his crest was the only thing holding him back from being able to reach his full potential.

Here is an image similar to his crest:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***[The Strongest Sage with the Weakest Crest](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=143878)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> In a certain world, there was someone who excelled in magic combat, people called him "Sage".
> Seeking the strongest combat art, he devoted himself to research every magic and combat arts in existence.
>
> And the conclusion he arrived at was very cruel: "My body is not fit for magic combat".
> Yet he didn't give up.
>
> He sealed his own soul with a magic art, to be reborn in a far-off future.
> And in the completely-changed world he saw in his new life, the magic theory was of unbelievably low level.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is the one thank you very much  for finding it for me i reallyappriciate it